# Excel - Return multiple column headings based on multiple "x" entries in a row in a table?

Tags: excel

If I have a table with various combinations of "x" in the columns of each row, against each row how do I write a formula that would return the column heading for each column where there is an "x". The cells without an "x" are blank, and would not return the column heading.

SO if my columns were called A, B, C and D and there was and x in column B and D only for that reference row, I would get a return of "B,D" as a comma separated string.

Thank you

Comment: You need to post your formula effort. It will be good to know Excel version as approach will differ depending on version.

Answer (score 0):

With O365 you can use following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(A1:D1,MMULT(COLUMN(A1:C1)^0,--(A2:D4="x"))))
```

[image]

In the `MMULT` function, the number of columns in the first parameter `COLUMN(A1:C1)` must correspond to the number of rows in the second parameter `A2:D4="x"`